# Rattling power supply

Tags: power-supply

So I bought this pc about 3 months ago, it ran all smooth all summer, now it starts to make a rattling noise, i checked all the fans, and it seems to be the power supply. I vacumed the filter and tried to remove as much dust from the outside, the noise settled down a bit but is still there and very noticable. Could it be that something inside the power supply is hitting the fan. 
Also, the noise is off and on, its not always here. When i play heavy games it shows more often, but at this very moment when im not playing its not making any noise... 
Is this an issue i should be concerned about or is it no problem at all? D:

Comment: Is it screwed in tightly?

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't move, i think its secured tightly yes

Comment: Possibly fan noise? Might be the CPU, graphics card or power supply fan. "Shows more often when playing games" points to graphics card fan (or maybe CPU). Fans have ball bearings that undergo wear. Cheap fans need replacement earlier, though 3 months is short even for cheap fans.

Comment: I checked both fans of graphic card, its not from graphic card, its 100% from the power supply

Comment: I don't think we can help. You've already come to the conclusion that it's the PSU!. The only option now is to send it back under warranty if it's only 3 months old, or take it to a PC repair shop. If unsure, borrow another PSU to confirm it by using the borrowed PSU in your computer to determine if the issue really is there (and not just around there).